# Filling space between coordinates

Tags: pgfplots, graphs, distributions, fillbetween

Because I failed to plot a cumulative distribution function, I tried to draw some paths (it´s just for demonstration purpose).
Unfortunately I can not fill the spaces between the two "functions".
The larger one should get a gray filling - the smaller one a black filling.
Can someone please help me!?

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,
    bibliography=totoc,
    toc=listof,
    %chapterentrydots=on,
    captions=tableheading,
    headings=small,
    listof=entryprefix]
    {scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                         
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                            
\usepackage[english,german,ngerman]{babel}                                          
\usepackage{lmodern}                                                                
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}       
\usepackage{microtype}                                                          
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[format=hang,skip=2.5pt,justification=RaggedRight,singlelinecheck=false,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}                                       
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr0.85\linewidth-3\tabcolsep\relax}}{#1}}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}                                                 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}
\setul{0.25ex}{}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
        \scalebox{3}{


\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:500,smooth,node distance = 0cm, auto]

  \pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
  \pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}

\begin{axis}[
      width=12cm,height=12cm,
      axis lines=middle,
      domain=0:400,
      smooth,
      no markers,
      xmin=0,xmax=350,
      tick style=white,
      xtick={0,100,200},
      xlabel={x},
      yticklabel style=white,
      xticklabel style=white,
      xlabel style={right},
      restrict y to domain=0:350,
      ymin=0,ymax=400,
      ytick={0,100,200,300}, 
      ylabel={F(x), G(x)},
      ylabel style={above}]

\end{axis}


\draw [name path=line1, black] plot [smooth,tension=0.4] coordinates {(0,0) (4.2976,1.1513) (7,8.5) (9.5,9.5)};
\draw [name path=line2,densely dotted, black] plot [smooth,tension=0.8] coordinates {(0,0) (3,2) (7,7.5) (9.5,9.5)};

\path [name path=1and2, intersection segments={of=line1 and line2,sequence={A1[reverse] -- B1}}];

\pgfonlayer{pre main}
\fill [black!40,intersection segments={
       of=1and2 and line2,
        sequence={A1 -- B1[reverse]},}];
\endpgfonlayer


\draw [black, densely dashed] (0,9.5) -- (9.5,9.5) -- (9.5,0);
\node [circle,inner sep=1pt, fill, radius=10pt] at (0,9.5) {};
\node [][left] at (0,9.5) {$1$};
\node [circle,inner sep=1pt, fill, radius=10pt] at (9.5,9.5) {};
\node [circle,inner sep=1pt, fill, radius=10pt][] at (9.5,0) {};


\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Meanwhile I managed to plot a Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) and @Zarko s reply works well. Unfortunately there are several issues coming up.

```
% gnuplot is needed
% enter "PATH": c:\programme\gnuplot\bin
% pdfLaTeX: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -enable-write18 %.tex

\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
\pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{pdflscape}


\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}


\def\cdf(#1)(#2)(#3){0.5*(1+(erf((#1-#2)/(#3*sqrt(2)))))}
\def\cdfx(#1)(#2)(#3){0.5*(1+(erf((#1-#2)/(#3*sqrt(2)))))}

\DeclareMathOperator{\CDF}{cdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      width=12cm,height=12cm,
      ymin=0,ymax=1.1,
      %xmin=-5.1, %Please turn on to see the "missing tail"!
      xmax=6,
      axis x line=center,
      axis y line=left,
      xlabel={$x$},
      xtick=\empty,
      xlabel style={right},
      ytick=\empty,
      ylabel={$F(x)$, $G(x)$},
      ylabel style={above}, %Why is this not working? Label still "left"
      smooth,
      no markers,
      clip=false
      ]


\addplot[smooth,black,name path=A, tick] gnuplot{\cdf(x)(0)(1)} node[right,pos=0.5, xshift=2ex]{$F$} node[right,pos=0.5, xshift=-12ex, yshift=0.75ex]{$G$};
\addplot[smooth,black,densely dashed,name path=B, tick]gnuplot{\cdfx(x+0.5)(0)(0,2)};
% Why is the tail on the left side of the graph missing?!

\pgfonlayer{pre main}
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B, split, every even segment/.style={black}]{black!35};
\endpgfonlayer


\draw [black, densely dotted](0,100)--(1000,100)--(1000,0);  

\node at (10,100){$1$}; % \node at (-10,100){$1$} Does not work - "1" disapears! 


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

1. The positioning of the label (Y axis) does not work.
2. The graphs` left tail is missing.
3. The node ("1") on the y axis disappears.

[image]

Any ideas?
Thank you so much!

Comment: please make your document example minimal (most of package is loaded twice, `xcolor` had to be before `tikz` etc.=, i,e, as minimal working example (mwe). now your code is not compilable. also use of `scalebox` on `tiktz`image is very fragile.

Comment: @Zarko I have the same problem and was wondering if this has to do with my tex installation, but apparently that's not the case.

Comment: i try to cleanup op code, so far unsuccessful, compilation always froze. i need more time to find the cause ...

Comment: @Zarko It stops freezing if you comment out `\pgfonlayer{pre main}` ... `\endpgfonlayer` (and the errors disappear once you remove some of the packages such as `textcomp` and `babel`).

Comment: @marmot, i give up with op code and wrote own, see  my answer below. i still need some effort to complete it, however, first i need to know, if i'm on the right way. observe used `pgfplots` version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i must confess that i was going to lost in your code ... but from description in your question, i guess that you looking something like this:

(first step of answer)

[image]

*mwe* which generate above image is:

```
 \documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}%1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta,
                calc,
                decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.pathreplacing,
                decorations.shapes, decorations.text,
                intersections,
                positioning,
                shadings, shapes}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
    \pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      width=12cm,height=12cm,
      axis lines=middle,
      xmin=0,xmax=11,
      xlabel={$x$},
      xtick={0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10},
      xlabel style={right},
      restrict y to domain=0:9,
      ymin=0,ymax=10,
      ylabel={$F(x)$, $G(x)$},
      ylabel style={above},
      domain=0:10,
      samples=40,
      smooth,
      no markers,
]

\draw [name path=A] plot coordinates {(0,0) (4.2976,1.1513) (7,8.5) (9.5,9.5)};
\draw [name path=B,densely dotted] plot coordinates {(0,0) (3,2) (7,7.5) (9.5,9.5)};
\pgfonlayer{pre main}
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B,
                 split,
                 every even segment/.style={red}
                 ]{blue}; % <-- added fill between paths A and B
\endpgfonlayer
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**

- in above *mwe* is used `pgfplotsd` version **1.15**. with version 1.68, which you use, doesn't work as desired. i strongly encourage you to upgrade your `pgfplots` installation to recent version.
- your image code is erroneous. with comparison observe difference between your code and above proposed one
- from `axis` parameters i remove all superfluous options.
- compilation of your *mwe* to get frozen

considering your document preamble, after its reorganization and dropping superfluous package, and small changes in image code and adding image parts dropped in the first step i obtain (second step);

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
               bibliography=totoc,
               toc=listof,
               %chapterentrydots=on,
               captions=tableheading,
               headings=small,
               listof=entryprefix]
               {scrbook}
% page layout
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

% encoding and babel
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,german,ngerman]{babel}
% fonts
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage{microtype}
% captions and figures
\usepackage[format=hang,
            skip=2.5pt,
            justification=RaggedRight,
            singlelinecheck=false,
            labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
% for tables
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, tabu, tabularx, tabulary}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr0.85\linewidth-3\tabcolsep\relax}}{#1}}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% for pgfplots and tikz images
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}% with version 1.8 doesn't work well
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta,
                calc,
                decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.pathreplacing,
                decorations.shapes, decorations.text,
                intersections,
                positioning,
                shadings, shapes}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
    \pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}% only for test purposes
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt,
            node contents={}}
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
      width=12cm,height=12cm,
      axis lines=middle,
      xmin=0,xmax=11,
      xlabel={$x$},
      xtick=\empty,
      xlabel style={right},
      restrict y to domain=0:9,
      ymin=0,ymax=10,
      ytick=\empty,
      ylabel={$F(x)$, $G(x)$},
      ylabel style={above},
      domain=0:10,
      samples=40,
      smooth,
      no markers,
      clip=false
]

\draw [name path=A,thick] plot coordinates {(0,0) (4.2976,1.1513) (7,8.5) (9.5,9.5)};
\draw [name path=B,thick,densely dotted] plot coordinates {(0,0) (3,2) (7,7.5) (9.5,9.5)};
\pgfonlayer{pre main}
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B,
                 split,
                 every even segment/.style={red!30}
                 ]{blue!30}; % <-- added fill between paths A and B
\endpgfonlayer
%
\draw [very thin, densely dashed]
        (0,9.5)     node[dot,label=left:???] --
        (9.5,9.5)   node[dot] --
        (9.5,0)     node[dot,label=below:1];
\node [circle,inner sep=1pt, fill, radius=10pt] at (0,9.5) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know that the old version was still running. Over the time I just added new packages when something did not work. :S So I think I will carefully reorganise my code.